# Floating Action Button (FAB) not being sticky when html page has scrollbar

Tags: button, twitter-bootstrap-3, scrollbar, floating, floating-action-button

I have created FAB button on page that has scroll bar. My expectation is FAB button will be sticky on right down corner when page is getting scrolled. However, the button also scroll with page. This gives indication that z-index of FAB is at same level as other HTML tags but in CSS, I have specifically given z-index of FAB as 1000 (so I expect it to be higher than other element on page)

I have created fiddle to replicate issue. Can anyone please check and provide corrective action

https://jsfiddle.net/jh7mv590/2/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
            <div id="inbox">
      <div class="fab btn-group show-on-hover dropup">
          <div data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Compose" style="margin-left: 42px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-io dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
            <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x fab-backdrop"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fab-primary"></i>
            <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-stack-1x fa-inverse fab-secondary"></i>
        </span>
      </button></div>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Coffee"><i class="fa fa-coffee"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="LiveChat"><i class="fa fa-comments-o"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Reminders"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Invites"><i class="fa fa-ticket"></i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but `position: fixed;` is probably what you are looking for.

```css
.show-on-hover {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px;
    right: 50px;
}
```